# How to restore jailbroken iPhone stuck in recovery mode without iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, jailbreak, restore, ipsw

I have a jailbroken iPhone 4 running on iOS 7.1.1. I checked Cydia and updated a few tweaks and since that update, my tweak called "f.lux" wasn't working so I deleted it. After deleting it, I would swipe to unlock my home screen but my phone would just shut off and restart. Restoring it in iTunes didn't work and errors would always pop up. I tried using TinyUmbrella and it didn't work. I also tried downloading an ipsw file but that doesn't seem to work either. Do I just need to buy a new phone or is there a way of fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

It’s not possible to do that without iTunes.

If you have a PC or Mac with iTunes installed, you can bring the device in DFU mode by performing the following steps:

- Connect the iPhone to your computer
- Press and hold the Home button and the Sleep button at the same time
- After 10 seconds, release the Sleep button
- Continue holding the Home button until this iTunes message shows up: "iTunes has detected an iPhone in recovery mode. You must restore this iPhone before it can be used with iTunes"

[image]

You can then restore it to the latest iOS version. Please be aware that this will erase **all the data** on your device and will restore it to the **latest** iOS version (iOS 8.1.1 as of Dec 1st, 2014).

Please note: In DFU mode, the iPhone’s screen will remain black until you invoke the firmware restore. If it shows a "Connect to iTunes" screen, you are not in DFU mode but in recovery mode.

Comment: i already tried restoring my phone while in DFU mode and it still didn't work. Should i try restoring it on another laptop?

Comment: If you used TinyUmbrella before, it may have altered your `/etc/hosts` file. This can be the reason for the iTunes restore errors. Could you check your hosts file if it contains `gs.apple.com` entries and if so, delete these rows?

Comment: where do i check for hosts files?

Comment: Depends wether you are on OS X or Windows. On OS X, you can enter `sudo nano /etc/hosts` in your terminal to modify it. In Windows, it’s located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`. To modify it, you’ll need to fire up Notepad as Administrator.

Comment: Hey, did this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:

Step 1: Disconnect the data cable and turn off your iPhone.

Step 2: Press the "Home" button and connect your iPhone to the computer with data cable, and then release the "Home" button.

Step 3: Now you have enter into recovery mode successfully.

Step 4: It is very easy for you to exit recovery mode. Please press both the "Home". button and "Power" button at the same time until the LOGO "white apple" appeared on the screen.